# Eclipse content assist (for PHP or anything) not using active working set

Tags: eclipse

The Eclipse content assist for PHP (and I'm assuming for other types as well) isn't using the currently active working set - it's searching ALL files in the project. How do I change it to only use the active working set?

When doing a Ctrl+Shift+R search, it was also looking for all files in the project (not what I wanted), until I clicked the small black triangle in that window and selected the working set I wanted it to use. Now it successfully only shows the files that match my search string in the working set. However, this doesn't change anything in the autocomplete content assist feature (i.e. doing a Ctrl+Space to complete the name of a function or variable). Is there any way to accomplish this?

I'm using Eclipse Indigo release, so it's very recent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not possible the way you put it. Eclipse Working Sets just give you a way to organize your projects.

However you may want to take a look at **Mylyn**, which is fully integrated with Eclipse platform. [Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mylyn1/) and [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mylyn2/) is a nice overview of what you can do with Mylyn. But briefly, what it allows you to do is to create a *task* and maintain a *context* associated with it. This way, only the relevant files will be displayed in **Project Explorer** and *autocomplete* would suggest you only *task-focused* options.